# Elastic Beanstalk rebuilding Docker image when using AWS CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I am currently working on a CI/CD pipeline (AWS CodePipeline with CodeBuild) for deploying the production stage of our application to elastic beanstalk (docker platform). I am using docker-compose for building and deploying.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` so far:

```
version: '3'
services:
  api: 
    container_name: "api"
    image: "***.dkr.ecr.***.amazonaws.com/api"
    build:
          context: .
    ports:
          - "80:5000"
```

However, the problem is that elastic beanstalk again builds the docker image when defining the `build` statement within the `docker-compose.yml`. Is there a way to avoid this since it is already built and pushed to ECR during the build-stage of the CI/CD pipeline?

A workaround. which worked for me, was to add a separate `docker-compose-build.yml` and exclude the `build` statement from `docker-compose.yml` but the problem here is that this does not work for our other stages. In detail, our test stage is usually deployed to elastic beanstalk by using the eb-cli and there we need elastic beanstalk to build the images locally without ECR.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a Dockerfile in the root of your app?

Comment: Yes we have a Dockerfile in our root.

Comment: I think it's building the image again due to the Dockerfile. Can you move the Dockerfile to another directory, and use [context](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) to find the file in a different location as needed?

Comment: This would be possible, however I would have the complete structure therefore. I managed to replace the docker-compose.yml within the pipeline. I basically have 3x docker-compose.yml 

- docker-compose.yml (for building the test stage directly on eb)
- docker-compose.build.yml (for building the image in the pipeline)
- docker-compose.deploy.yml (for deploying the image in the pipeline)

docker-compose.deploy.yml is renamed during the build to docker-compose.yml and it does not contain the build command. 

Anyway, thank you for your help!